# Efficient implementation of stacks in C

Tags: c, algorithm, performance, data-structures, stack

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal-stacks
For this problem, I tried to implement the stack data structure in c. But I am getting timeout for some cases using the following code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
struct Stack{
    int top;
    int size;
    int sum;
    int* arr;
};
struct Stack* createStack(int size){
    struct Stack* stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    stack->size=size;
    stack->top=-1;
    stack->sum=0;
    stack->arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    return stack;
}
int isempty(struct Stack* stack){
    if(stack->top==-1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
void push(struct Stack* stack,int term){
    stack->top++;
    stack->arr[stack->top]=term;
    stack->sum+=term;
}
void pop(struct Stack* stack){
    if(isempty(stack)==0){
        stack->sum-=stack->arr[stack->top];
        stack->top--;
    }
}
int main(){
    int size1,size2,size3;
    scanf("%d %d %d",&size1,&size2,&size3);
    int arr1[size1];
    for(int i=0;i<size1;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
    struct Stack* stack1 = createStack(size1);
    for(int i=size1-1;i>=0;i--)
        push(stack1,arr1[i]);
    int arr2[size2];
    for(int i=0;i<size2;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr2[i]);
    struct Stack* stack2 = createStack(size2);
    for(int i=size2-1;i>=0;i--)
        push(stack2,arr2[i]);
    int arr3[size3];
    for(int i=0;i<size3;i++)
        scanf("%d",&arr3[i]);
    struct Stack* stack3 = createStack(size3);
    for(int i=size3-1;i>=0;i--)
        push(stack3,arr3[i]);
    while(stack1->sum!=stack2->sum || stack2->sum!=stack3->sum){
        if(stack1->sum > stack2->sum && stack1->sum > stack3->sum)
            pop(stack1);
        if(stack2->sum > stack1->sum && stack2->sum > stack3->sum)
            pop(stack2);
        if(stack3->sum > stack2->sum && stack3->sum > stack1->sum)
            pop(stack3);
    }
    printf("%d\n",stack1->sum);
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better approach using only the stack data structure (preferably in C) ?

Comment: why not use linked list instead of array for internal storage ?

Comment: You let the code provided as a start at hackerrank goad you into solving this using stacks (which may be an acceptable purpose for an exercise like this). Think about what you could do _reading the values of the second stack_.

Comment: (Think about [const correctness](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). For a more versatile stack, have `pop()` return the former top. Consider declaring `long sum;`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you might be getting time limit exceeded is because your while loop never ends if

a) Any stack becomes empty. You should add that check in the while loop condition that none of the stacks is empty and then output the minimum sum of all the three stacks.

b) There might be a case where the heights are 20, 10, 10, in that case how would your code work?

Comment: ....u were correct about the point (b)....but regarding point (a) in the pop function I have taken the condition is empty. The judge accepted the answer if i included the condition `>=` instead of `>` in the if conditions.....Thnx..!!

Answer (score 2):

You can speed things up by determining which stack has the highest sum, and then pop from that stack until its sum is equal to or less than the lowest sum.

Code to find the stacks with the highest and lowest sums could look like this

```
struct Stack *high = (stack1->sum > stack2->sum) ? stack1 : stack2;
struct Stack *low  = (high == stack1) ? stack2 : stack1;

if ( stack3->sum > high->sum )
    high = stack3;
else if ( stack3->sum < low->sum )
    low = stack3;
```

Then the code to reduce the highest sum looks like this

```
while ( high->sum > low->sum )
    pop( high );
```

Comment: `if(stack1->sum > stack2->sum && stack1->sum > stack3->sum)` , `if(stack2->sum > stack1->sum && stack2->sum > stack3->sum)` , ` if(stack3->sum > stack2->sum && stack3->sum > stack1->sum)` .......isn't it the same thing which I have done?....correct me if I m wrong.

Comment: @yobro97 There were other flaws in your code as pointed out in the accepted answer. In particular, consider what happens when the sums are 20,20, and 10. Since your code looks for one stack to be higher than both other stacks, it won't do anything if the two largest stacks are equal. But this answer would choose `stack2` as `high` and `stack3` as `low`, and would pop from `stack2`.

Comment: Having said that, I didn't fully analyze your code to find that problem. I just had a bad feeling about the way the loop was written: way too many branch points. Branch points (places in the code where the processor needs to make a decision) can slow a processor down significantly (by causing pipeline stalls). Your code has 8 branch points in the loop (not counting the branch points in the `pop` function). My code has 1. So my loop will run faster. As it turns out, that wasn't the problem, but my solution would have fixed the problem nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion......I didn't have the knowledge about `Branch points`....it would definitely help me...one question though.....how significantly does it affect the running time?

Comment: @yobro97 In this example (replacing 8 branch points with 1), I would expect the **loop** code to run 2 to 3 times faster. However, it depends a lot on the data in the stacks, since that affects the number of branches actually taken. There's also the time spent in other parts of the code. For example, If loading the stacks using `scanf` takes a long time compared with running the loop, then speeding up the loop by 2 to 3 times may only reduce the overall running time by 10 to 20%. That's where [profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) comes in.